# JavaScript Facebook Fan Gate without Permissions

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm in the process of building a fan gate using facebook's javascript sdk.  I'd like to determine if the user has "liked" my page so I can display / hide content.  Currently, if I use the javascript sdk, the user is prompted with permissions which is what I'd like to avoid.

Has anyone successfully achieved this in javascript?  I'm able to do this without issue in PHP but unfortunately, we are not able to use php in our current project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on the client side.  Facebook sends an HTTP POST request and you need to process the signed_request post variable which requires server code to access.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in a Facebook tab, you can use the PHP SDK and read the signed request:

```
$request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$isFan = $request['page']['liked'];
```

If you are not in a tab, there is no reliable way of checking "like" status without permissions.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you can't use PHP. Using whichever server-side language you have available, the logic remains the same on the Facebook tab. Again, no reliable way of doing it outside a tab without permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's all gotta be client side but the good news is the app will be in an iframe on a pages's tab.

Comment: That's good that it's on the tab, but the only way to get that like info is to read the signed request. I don't believe that's possible on the client side, but if it is, "signed request" is what you'll want to search under.